# How to get asynchronous value in function python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, asynchronous

```
async def fun():
     return {id:1}


async def fun2():
     var=await fun()
     print(var.id)
     
fun2()
```

#output : <coroutine object fun2 at 0x7faad2f70640>

I just want to get the id value in fun2, kindly explain me how should i do this

Answer (score 1):

```
import asyncio
async def fun():
    return {'_id':1}


async def fun2():
    var = await fun()
    print(var)

asyncio.run(fun2())
```

Comment: its returning None

Comment: That’s because your function `fun2` doesn’t return a value

Comment: Edit code into your question, as text not a picture

Comment: Forgot the underscore in `_id`

Comment: if i try to return var.get('id') it return None

Comment: @KanavRaina I updated the variable in `fun` to be `_id`, because `id` is a keyword. Try the code now.

Comment: ``asyncio.run`` should be preferred over interacting with the loop directly.

Comment: Updated to use `asyncio.run`

Comment: Please don't create tasks only to immediately ``await`` them! One can directly ``await fun()``.

Comment: `{'id': 1}` would be fine, because a dict key (`'id'`) is never used in a place where it could clash with the builtin `id` function.

Comment: True. Personal preference. Earlier comment was to provide reasoning for why `var.get('id')` was returning `None`

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi for the insight. Updated.